# Re-routing http requests based on full domain name

Tags: apache, tomcat, url-routing, port

lets say I have multiple http servers on each thinkable technology out there. For example Apache for PHP, Tomcat for JSP and so on... running on one machine with one physical interface with one public IP.

Now, I want all of them to respond on same port, 80 of course. Which is not possible since one app = one port using TCP/IP. I know, apache for example can integrate Tomcat, and handle requests on .jsp pages to him, but I am thinking of different, more universal apprach.

Is is possible, maybe better question would be, is there any app that can pre-filter http requests and than forward them to different port? Based on domain requested? Both ways? So client would think he is talking to port 80, but internally he would be served by Tomcat running on port 8080? I hope you know what I mean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a reverse proxy such as apache mod_proxy. The reverse proxy reroutes the incoming requests to the right server, even if all the servers are on the same physical host.

> Reverse proxies can be used whenever multiple web servers must be accessible via a single public IP address. The web servers listen on different ports in the same machine, with the same local IP address or, possibly, on different machines and different local IP addresses altogether. The reverse proxy analyses each incoming call and delivers it to the right server within the local area network.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy